# Laravel redirect route is not working using return but if i use echo its working why?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I got this weird experience with laravel `redirect->route('routeName')`. Here is the code:

```
public static function loginCheckWithRedirect($routeName = false){

    if(functions::loginCheck()){
        if($routeName && is_string($routeName)){
            return redirect()->route($routeName);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

If I use `echo  redirect()->route($routeName)`, it works. But `return redirect()->route($routeName)` does not. Why?

Comment: What does php artisan route:list show for the $routeName you're trying to redirect to? Do you have a route with that name registered?

Comment: @btl im not sure what do you mean but on my route list method column i got  GET|HEAD for the route  i want to redirect.

Comment: show your route file

Comment: Give an example of what $routeName might be.

Comment: lets say  i have this  route Route::get('/sometext','controller@func')->name('newRoute');  Now ill call the function Classexample::loginCheckWithRedirect('newRoute');

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the difference between `return` and `echo`

1. `Return`: when you call a method from another method, and you return some data, the return data will take the place of the method called.
2. `Echo`: when you use echo, it will not return some data to the calling or main function but it will display the data directly.

`Example`

```
function myFun($param){
    return $param;
}

function ini(){
    myFun("Hello!");
}
```

**The above codes will display nothing on the user's screen because you did not add a display code in any of the function.**

But if you use either:

```
function myFun($param){
    return $param;
}

function ini(){
    echo myFun("Hello!");
}
```

Or:

```
function myFun($param){
    echo $param;
}

function ini(){
    myFun("Hello!");
}
```

The output will be `Hello!`

Coming back to your question, ***You need to either echo the redirect call in the called method or you return the returned redirect call in the caller method***

This is what I did:

`Route file`

```
    use App\Http\Controllers\TestController;

Route::get('/', function(){
    return TestController::loginCheckWithRedirect('myRoute');
});

Route::get('/test', function(){
   return 'Redirected...';
})->name("myRoute");
```

`TestController`

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public static function loginCheckWithRedirect($routeName = false){

        if(functions::loginCheck()){
            if($routeName && is_string($routeName)){
                return redirect()->route($routeName);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The above code redirects properly. Hope this was helpful to you...

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly.

I guess the problem is with your route file (`web.php` if you are using laravel 5.4).

This is what I did:

```
Route::get('/test/{routeName}','HomeController@loginCheckWithRedirect')->name('test');
Route::get('/admin/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
```

Replace `HomeController` with your controller. Make sure not to remove `/{routeName}` if you want to change the url.

Example : `localhost:3000/test/admin.login` will open the admin login page since the route name is `admin.login` as seen in the code above.

Comment: thank you for taking look on to it, i think its not the web.php because some other controllers that i use redirect()->route() are all working.

Comment: What I mean is the way you wrote the route in your `web.php`